# How can I use the PreAuthetication between 2 web-apps using Spring to avoid the login inside the second app after signed in the first one?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, pre-authentication

I'm trying to implement a `PreAuthetication` system using Spring, but I don't understand how it's work.

I have an application `A`, where the users can sign in. After that the user can enter into another application `B`. But I don't want that the users have to do another login.

So where I have to put the configuration? Inside the application A or B or both?

I tried to use the `Siteminder` config but it doesn't work with the configuration inside the app `B`. I have this error:

> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException:
>   SM_USER header not found in request.
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:48)

Answer (score 0):

To configure a PreAuthentication system using Spring Security, you should implement your own Authentication Filter.

To do so, you have to extends one of the Pre-Authentication Framework Classes of Spring Security (Check this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html), and override the methods to get the authentication information you received from the application A.

Let's imagine you get the information from an HTTP request.
In this case you extend `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`, and by overriding `getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request)`, you will be able to get the credentials to set the authenticated user and its authorities according to what was in the request.

The method doFilter looks at every single request, which allows to always check if the authentication information are correct.

Once you've correctly implemented the filter, you set it as the authentication filter using `http.addFilterBefore(...)` inside the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` of SecurityConfiguration.

Here is a very simplified example of the method which allows you to get the credentials :

```
@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String[] credentials = new String[1];
    credentials[0] = request.getHeader(Constants.SM_USER);
    return credentials;
}
```

**Edit**

A way to send the information from app A to app B, is to create an http request with the headers containing the credentials.
With Angular, you could do something like this:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

export class AppComponent {
  email = '';
  first_name = '';
  last_name = '';
  password = '';
  url = '/app2';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login() {
    let headerDict = {
      'USR_F_NAME': this.first_name,
      'USR_L_NAME': this.last_name,
      'USR_EMAIL': this.email,
      'USR_PSWRD': this.password
    }

    let headers: Headers = new Headers(headerDict);
    let requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(this.url, requestOptions);
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form>
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input name="first_name" required [(ngModel)]="first_name">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input name="last_name" required [(ngModel)]="last_name">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" required [(ngModel)]="password">
    <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Update**

[As there were some problems when trying to send the information through request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882425/8800147), I created a repository on GitHub in which you will find two JHipster application.

`sendAuthInfo` (port 8080) and `getAuthInfo` (port 8081)

The first one is used to login. Once you have entered the info, you are redirected with **url parameters** and logged in.

You need to add a password and customize the user so it has the info you need.

[Here is the GitHub repo.](https://github.com/brice-julien/jhipster-preauth)

Comment: I'm interested too.. Could you be a bit more clear? I don't understand it very well.. Or if you know a good example, or explanation, could you add the link? For example, how can I send the credential from an app to another? For instance, if I use a link, `<a href="the_second_app" ....'>ClickMe</a>`, is it possible pass to the second app the credentials?

Comment: I edited the answer to add an example of how you could send the information. I added the credentials in the request headers and since the app B check each request with doFilter(), you will be able to get these headers in app B. I don't have any link to an example, but when I will have time I can try to put one on github

Comment: And if I use jsp or thymeleaf, do you know a way to do that? If I use a li, maybe I should intercept the requiest with the controller and the resend the new request with the new header... I don't know... :)

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by a li ? But you can send the request with Java (better) or JavaScript I think. Also, I would hash the password in server-side before sending it, so it doesn't appear clearly in the header

Comment: Ops.. Typo.. It is "link"

Comment: I updated my answer to add the example. It's more than basic, but at least you see how to add the filter and get te information