# Angular 5 - How to redirect to an external url with specific headers?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http-headers

This is what I am trying to achieve with Angular :

```
this.headers = ...;

this.http.get(`${urlApi}`).subscribe(data => {
    // go to url with specific headers
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I get the response of a get request from my server, I want to redirect to an external url with specific headers, to be able communicate some information between two apps.

There must be a way to do this. I know it's not possible using `window.location.href`.

Comment: I also need to know how to send the headers while calling external urls. Let me know if you got it how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From what I have learnt, this is a redirection, not a request : this means you can't add headers to your redirect.

**But**, what you can do, is send URL params to your second application.

In your URL, simply append

```
?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 /// etc.
```

At the end of your URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know I can do this way, but I really would like to use headers. You are saying it's *a redirection not a request*. There must be a way to make a request to another app. If I try this : **this.http.get('otherAppUrl')** The other app get the info, but I stay on the first app

Comment: Because it is an HTTP call, a REST call. You are fetching data, not redirecting. I'm not an expert at web technologies, but I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible. If I had to do this, I would do what I've told you.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will do this way, if there is no other idea I will accept your answer

Comment: I would say keep digging, and if you find the solution you want, could you please keep me updated ? This interests me a lot !

Comment: No problem, I will !

Comment: @br.julien , have you got to know how to send headers with external urls? I also need to know for my project.